# Are organisms that are genetically modified with a deletion classified as "transgenic"?

Tags: terminology, crispr, animal-models, animal-husbandry

Imagine you delete a genomic region in a zygote with a CRISPR plasmid to generate an F1 animal with a genomic deletion.

The animal should be considered transgenic because of the presence of the plasmid DNA. But in the nuclear DNA, no foreign DNA has been introduced, it's only had a segment removed.

But when F2 are produced from two such animals, are *they* considered transgenic? They shouldn't inherit the plasmid DNA from their parents, right? And they have no foreign DNA in their nuclei.

In my own project, we used "transgenic" mice that bore a genetic deletion. But they also had the Cre recombinase or LoxP sequences in their genomes, hence they'd qualify as transgenic despite the deletion. But what about when there are no foreign sequences introduced, only deleted?

Comment: In Australia, gene deletions still count as genetically modified. See “the office of the gene technology regulator”